# Enable TLS1.3 on windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: openssl

How to enable the TLS1.3 on windows server 2012 R2.
I was able to enable TSL1.3 on LINUX but not on windows.

https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a433/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx
Tried whatever mentioned in the above link, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

idk, if it may help you, but I installed .Net framework 4.8 on 2012 R2 server.

Then I was able to use tls13 in my .net application.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4503548/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows

It includes system updates:

> In Windows Server 2012, Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4486081) is
>   displayed under Installed Updates in Control Panel. In Windows RT 8.1,
>   Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2, Update for Microsoft Windows
>   (KB4486105) is displayed under Installed Updates in Control Panel.

You also may try to install these updates only, but I am not sure about that  at all.

Comment: .NET relies on the underlying OS to provide the TLS version (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/microsoft-tls-1-3-support-reference/).
TLS 1.3 is only supported in Windows Server 2022 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to enable TLS 1.3 on Windows Server 2012 R2 as of October 2020. Windows Server 2012 R2 does not support TLS 1.3.